# add_rewrite_rule fro html to another url not working

Tags: url-rewriting, redirect, urls, htaccess

I want to redirect mywebsite.com/anyname.html to mywebsite.com/product/anyname For that I write the following query in functions.php . But it is not working . Please see my code below

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^(.*)\.html$', '/product/$1');
}

add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Please help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just add the relevant directive to the top of the `.htaccess` file directly. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ /product/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This matches `/anyname.html` (as in your example), but not `/foo/bar/anyname.html`.

Comment: thank you for the support. But i want to do this in functions.php